# SignalR and SelfHost in F#

Tags: asp.net, f#, signalr, owin

I think this will be quick answer, but I couldn't find the right answer during today. I trying create F# SignalR Self-Host application ( I followed this tutorial http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host)

The outcome is my application don't map signalr/hubs on my localhost, there is no error message (only from JavaScript file when it doesn't find client).

```
namespace Program

open Owin
open Dynamic
open Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
open Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs
open Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
open Microsoft.Owin.Cors
open System
open System.Diagnostics

type MyHub =
   inherit Hub
   member x.Send (name : string) (message : string) =
       base.Clients.All?addMessage name message

type MyWebStartUp() =
    member x.Configuration (app :IAppBuilder) =
       app.UseCors CorsOptions.AllowAll |> ignore
       app.MapSignalR() |> ignore
       ()

module Starter =

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let hostUrl = "http://localhost:8085"
    let disposable = WebApp.Start<MyWebStartUp>(hostUrl)
    Console.WriteLine("Server running on "+ hostUrl)
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    disposable.Dispose() 
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

I created C# application first and it does work perfectly, I assume my F# code is not right, but I cannot find that bug. For reference here is whole project: https://github.com/MartinBodocky/SignalRFSharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the [action overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn300218(v=vs.111).aspx) of `Start`, you don't have to make a whole type just for the start up configuration. Also you should definitely use `use` instead of manually disposing.

```
    let startup (a:IAppBuilder) =
       a.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll) |> ignore
       a.MapSignalR() |> ignore
    use app = WebApp.Start(hostUrl, startup)
```

But that's just to make the code nicer, there is a problem with your hub code because the Dynamic module you brought can only invoke a method with one argument, use [FSharp.Interop.Dynamic](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic#fsharpdynamic--) (in nuget) for a robust DLR `?` Operator.

```
open EkonBenefits.FSharp.Dynamic
type MyHub() =
    inherit Hub()
    member this.Send (name : string) (message : string) =
        this.Clients.All?addMessage(name,message) |> ignore
```